# Dockerfile with condition operating system

Tags: dockerfile

How can I query the operating system in Dockerfile.

I would like to give a different path for the download.

```
# ioncube loader
RUN curl -fSL 'http://downloads3.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz' -o ioncube.tar.gz \
    && mkdir -p ioncube \
    && tar -xf ioncube.tar.gz -C ioncube --strip-components=1 \
    && rm ioncube.tar.gz \
    && mv ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_7.4.so /var/www/ioncube_loader_lin_7.4.so \
    && rm -r ioncube
```

I'm using the latest Docker version with ddev.

Comment: Are you trying to use a docker image for multi architecture?

Comment: For example I have ddev running with Linux. Others have a Mac. Mac users cannot install an IonCube using the ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz file. It needs another file for that.